# how to direct a user to the download page of "Google play services"

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app crashes if a device does not have "Google Play Services" installed in it or if "Google Play Services" in not updated.
I want to direct a user to the download page of "Google play Services" if he does not have Play Services installed in his device.
I have applied an exception but what should I put in the catch block?
I mean how to direct user to the download page of Play Services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)` to get a `status`. If the status is not `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`, call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)` -- if that returns `true`, you should be able to use `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()` to display a dialog that will lead the user to download the Play Services Framework.

Comment: thank you for your answer. now I'm able to show a dialogue that says Play Services is not installed. but clicking the "ok" button of the dialogue simply takes me back to my app, not to the download page of play services.

Comment: @user2755646: If there is no option in that dialog to let the user download the Play Services Framework, then in Google's estimation, there is no way to get the Play Services Framework on that device. For example, if the device does not have the Play Store or Android Market on it, there is no way for the user to legitimately get the Play Services Framework.

Comment: @user2755646 , what solution did u find out to the problem of not being directed to plays store

Answer (score 1):

I think it is too late to answer this, but it could help other people.

Implement this method which check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK, If it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.

```
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.e("GooglePlayServices", "Google play services not working.");
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, 9000)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.e("GooglePlayServices", "GCM - This device is not supported.");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)